# Logstash monitoring not working for pipeline, reloads and events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to use logstash pipeline monitoring using the official api guide for ES
7.17 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/node-info-api.html

The jvm, process and os monitoring works for me, but the **pipeline, reloads and events** monitoring returns

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "request [/_node/stats/pipelines] contains unrecognized metric: [pipelines]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/_node/stats/pipelines] contains unrecognized metric: [pipelines]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL is

```
_node/stats/pipelines
```

Not

```
_nodes/stats/pipelines
     ^
     |
```

Comment: I noticed that earlier, I am getting the error in the question using "_node"

Comment: That's not what the error says. Can you share the command you're running?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I changed it in the original question

Comment: GET /_node/stats/pipelines?pretty

Comment: What happens if you don't specify `pipelines`?

Comment: Using only GET /_node/stats I get the correct output